# Why strtoul doesn't work as expected?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Hi I wrote a small test program to check how the function I wrote to convert string (an hexadecimal number) into a unsigned integer and I found that the code behave differently depending on the compiler or system I use.

I compiled the code below on:
(1) ideone C++4.3.2 https://ideone.com/LlcNWw
(2) g++ 4.4.7 on a centos6 (64bits)
(3) g++ 4.6.3 on an ubuntu12 (64bits)
(4) g++ 4.9.3 in a cygwin (32bits) environment

As expected (1) and (4) return AND IT'S exactly the correct result as the 1st value '0x210000000' is to big for a 32bit value....

```
Error while converting Id (0x210000000).
success
```

but (2) and (3) return

```
success
success
```

SO THE QUESTION is why the same simple C code build on different platform with different compiler return the same result... and Why 'strtoul("0x210000000", ....)' doesn't set 'errno' to 'ERANGE' to said that the bit 33 to 37 are out of range.

more trace on a the platform (3) give:

```
Id (0x210000000) as ul = 0x10000000  - str_end  - errno 0.
sucess
Id (0x10000000) as ul = 0x10000000  - str_end  - errno 0.
sucess




   /* strtoul example */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* strtoul */
#include <errno.h>

signed int GetIdentifier(const char* idString)
{
  char *str_end;
  int id = -1;
  errno = 0;
  id = strtoul(idString, &str_end, 16);
  if ( *str_end != '\0' || (errno == ERANGE))
  {
    printf("Error while converting Id (%s).\n", idString);
    return -1;
  }

  // Return error if converted Id is more than 29-bit
  if(id > 0x1FFFFFFF)
  {
    printf("Error: Id (%s) should fit on 29 bits (maximum value: 0x1FFFFFFF).\n", idString);
    return -1;
  }
  printf("sucess\n");
  return id;
}


int main ()
{
  GetIdentifier("0x210000000");
  GetIdentifier("0x10000000");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: 0x210000000 => more than 4 octets, not UL, but ULL

Comment: The different integer types and their sizes are mentioned very early on in any decent beginner-level C programming book. And generally, using an `int` or any other signed type to store a hexadecimal number doesn't make any sense. What do you think strto**ul** does? Ensure that compiler warnings are enabled.

Comment: BTW: `if ( *str_end != '\0' || (errno == ERANGE))` fails to detect a no conversion as in `id = strtoul("", &str_end, 16);`  Suggest `if ( str_end == idString || *str_end != '\0' || (errno == ERANGE))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value `0x210000000` is larger than 32 bits, and on 32 bit systems `long` is usually 32 bits which means you can't use `strtoul` to convert the string correctly. You need to use `strtoull` and use `unsigned long long` which is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits.

Of course, `long long` and [`strtoull`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul) was introduced in C99, so you might need to add e.g. `-std=c99` (or use a later standard like C11) to have it build correctly.

---

The problem, it seems, is that you assume that `long` is *always* 32 bits, when in fact it's defined to be *at least* 32 bits. See e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Properties) for the minimum bit-size of the standard integer types.

On some platforms and compilers, `long` can be bigger than 32 bits. Linux on 64-bit hardware is a typical such platform where `long` is bigger, namely 64 bits, which is of course well enough to fit `0x210000000`, which leads to `strtoul` not giving an error.

Comment: downvoted, I mentionned that the EXPECTED result was error for '0x210000000'. I'm not a beginner and if I wanted to get 64bit value I will have use the 'ull' function... please re-read the question

Comment: @alexbuisson Then I don't really get your question. If you expect the the to-big value to fail on 32 bit systems, you would of course expect it to succeed on 64 bit systems, right? For case 2 and 3, what result *did* you expect? I don't see what "mistake" you could possibly have made other than not expecting `long` to be 64 bits on 64 bit systems. The `long` type, just like all the other types, can have different sizes, and is *at least* 32 bits, but could be larger, and on e.g. Linux on a 64-bit system using GCC or Clang, then `long` is 64 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is also incorrect in assuming a successful call will not change the value of `errno`.  Per the [Linux `errno` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html):

> The `<errno.h>` header file defines the integer variable `errno`,
>   which is set by system calls and some library functions in the event
>   of an error to indicate what went wrong.  Its value is significant
>   only the return value of the call indicated an error (i.e., -1 from
>   most system calls; -1 or NULL from most library functions); **a
>   function that succeeds is allowed to change `errno`**.

(POSIX does place greater restrictions on `errno` modification by successful calls, but Linux doesn't strictly adhere to POSIX in many cases, and after all, **G**NU's **N**ot **U**nix...)

[The `strtoul` man page states](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtoul.3.html):

> The `strtoul()` function returns either the result of the conversion
>   or, if there was a leading minus sign, the negation of the result of
>   the conversion represented as an unsigned value, unless the original
>   (nonnegated) value would overflow; in the latter case, strtoul()
>   returns `ULONG_MAX` and sets errno to `ERANGE`.  Precisely the same
>   holds for strtoull() (with `ULLONG_MAX` instead of `ULONG_MAX`).

Unless `strtoul` returned `ULONG_MAX`, the value of `errno` after a call to `strtoul` is indeterminate.

Comment: true, but adding check that 'id != ULONG_MAX' will not help because in my case when 'strtoul' process ''0x210000000' in the cases (2) & (3) I got: 'errno' equal to 0, 'id' equal to '0x10000000' so it's not 'ULONG_MAX'

Comment: @alexbuisson What do the `errno` and `strtoul` man pages say on your installation?

Comment: OP's use of `errno` appears correct per C11 7.5  3 "The value of errno may be set to nonzero by a library function call whether or not there is an error, **provided the use of `errno` is not documented in the description of the function** in this International Standard." and §7.22.1.4 8 "If the correct value is outside the range of representable values, `LONG_MIN`, `LONG_MAX`, ...  is returned ..., and the value of the macro `ERANGE` is stored in errno."  Since `errno` is documented with `strtoul()`, it must follow that and not the general "whether or not there is an error".

Comment: @chux Yes.  Hence my parenthetical mention of POSIX in my answer.  But the OP states he's calling `strtoul` with a value that overflows, but it sets `errno` to `ERANGE` without returning `ULONG_MAX`.  Assuming it's Linux, it's not even following it's own documented behavior.  Saying *it must follow that [POSIX] and not the general "whether or not there is an error"* might be setting standards a bit too high...

Comment: Yes OP's code is problematic: code does not use `ULONG_MAX` but `0x1FFFFFFF` and assigns the return to `int id` which likely took on a negative value, thus failing to be detected in the "Return error if converted Id is more than 29-bit" test.  As [@Lundin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744066/why-strtoul-doesnt-work-as-expected/35744701?noredirect=1#comment59162161_35744066) comments