# unsigned long int strtoul(const char *str,char **endptr, int base). i do not understand the base

Tags: c

When I run the program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char stringnumber[]="2002200345345345";
    char *ptr_end;
    long answer;

    answer=strtoul(stringnumber,&ptr_end,10);
    printf("the unsigned number is : %lu \n",answer);
    return 0;
}
```

instead of getting  "2002200345345345" this number i am getting:

```sh
unsigned number is: 4294967295
```

Comment: Hi! welcome to [SO] :-) I am going to edit your question because you should not really put images in, rather also put in your output as formatted code. The trouble that you are running into is integer overflow; we'll get to the answer shortly

Comment: Works ok [here](https://ideone.com/8ACazT). Probably your system uses only 32 bits for `long` and not 64 bits. If that is the case then a `long` cannot fit that number.

Comment: `long answer;` should be `unsigned long answer;`, but I guess you are compiling on a system with 32-bit long.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why strtoul doesn't work as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744066/why-strtoul-doesnt-work-as-expected)

Comment: This code doesn't do any error checking.

Comment: Note that your wrong number is 2^32-1. OTOH strtoul is specified to return ULONG_MAX n case of overflow. I wonder if these two facts are connected somehow.

Comment: From the man page: `The strtoul(), strtoull(), strtoumax() and strtouq() functions return either the result of the conversion or, if there was a leading minus sign, the negation of the result
     of the conversion, unless the original (non-negated) value would overflow; in the latter case, strtoul() returns ULONG_MAX, strtoull() returns ULLONG_MAX, strtoumax()
     returns UINTMAX_MAX, and strtouq() returns ULLONG_MAX.`. Your value overflows, so you get ULONG_MAX.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Man pages are not good sources for answering C questions because they contain Unix extensions that are not guaranteed by the C standard.

Comment: You should use strtoull instead because strtoul is limited to unsigned long which is only 32 bits on your OS.

Answer (score 4):

The function [`strtoul`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul) will return [`ULONG_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) if the converted value is not representable as an `unsigned long`.

You appear to be using a platform on which `ULONG_MAX` is defined as `4,294,967,295`, which means that `unsigned long` is 32 bits wide on your platform.

You can determine whether a range error occurred in `strtoul` by checking whether that function set `errno` to `ERANGE`.

I suggest that you change your code to the following, so that it does extra validation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    char stringnumber[] = "2002200345345345";
    char *ptr_end;
    long answer;

    //set errno to 0, so that we can later check whether it
    //was modified by "strtoul"
    errno = 0;

    //attempt to convert string to integer
    answer = strtoul( stringnumber, &ptr_end, 10 );

    //check for conversion failure
    if ( ptr_end == stringnumber )
    {
        printf( "conversion failure!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //check for range error
    if ( errno == ERANGE )
    {
        printf( "out of range error!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //conversion was successful, so print the result
    printf( "the unsigned number is : %lu \n", answer );

    return 0;
}
```

This program has the following output on 64-bit Microsoft Windows (on which `unsigned long` is 32 bits wide):

```
out of range error!
```

On 64-bit Linux (on which `unsigned long` is 64 bits wide), it has the following output:

```
the unsigned number is : 2002200345345345
```

Instead of converting the number to an `unsigned long`, you may want to consider converting it to an `unsigned long long` instead. This type is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits wide and able to represent numbers up to at least `18,446,744,073,709,551,615` on all platforms. If you want to use `unsigned long long`, you should use the function `strtoull` instead.